# Show modal after installation or update of app

Tags: android, modal-dialog

A lot of Android apps now display a modal with the most recent changelog after it is installed or updated.

How can I display a scrollable modal after the application is initially installed or updated?

Comment: This post has an answer for that with example source code. http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-show-whats-new-dialog-in-android-app/

Comment: Switched answer as code.google.com is no longer available

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ended up with the following code
Part 1. Checking if the changelog should be viewed

```
        //evaluate if we will show changelog
    try {
        //current version
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode; 

        //version where changelog has been viewed
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SAPNotePreferences.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        int viewedChangelogVersion = settings.getInt(SAPNotePreferences.KEY_CHANGELOG_VERSION_VIEWED, 0);

        if(viewedChangelogVersion<versionCode) {
            Editor editor=settings.edit();
            editor.putInt(SAPNotePreferences.KEY_CHANGELOG_VERSION_VIEWED, versionCode);
            editor.commit();
            displayChangeLog();
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("Unable to get version code. Will not show changelog", e);
    }
```

Part 2 displaying the changelog dialog

```
        //load some kind of a view
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.changelog_view, null);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Changelog")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details)
    .setView(view)
    .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          //
      }
    }).show();
```

Part 3 the layout with the changelog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/aboutscrollview" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <TextView android:text="Thanks for installing ..."
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="15px"              
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff" />  
                    <TextView android:text="Changes: "
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                            android:paddingTop="15px"
                            android:paddingLeft="15px"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                    <TextView android:text="v2.0:changes..."
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="15px"      
                            android:paddingBottom="10px"            
                            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                    </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>                   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using the long layout for the dialog instead of using one long string and `setMessage`?

Answer (score 18):

[Try this](http://petoria.de/android-change-log/):

> With **Android Change Log** you can easily create, show and maintain an Android change log dialog.
>
> Features are:
>
> - display only what's new or the whole change log
> - display on first start of newly installed app or new app version
> - write the change log in a simplified language but also use HTML and CSS if needed...

Comment: At first I was a little disappointed when I saw that I'd had an answer unaccepted over a year later. Looking at this, though, this is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Why should i try this? Being that google code is no longer operational, is there a more recent source for this?

Comment: @TinyGiant I updated the link in this post.

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably on the right track. For #1, I have a class that inherits off of dialog, and its layout simply has a ScrollView containing a TextView, and then a "dismiss" button after that.

Regarding #2, what I've done in mine is to store a setting for LastVersionNotesSeen that holds the ... well, the version number for the notes last displayed. :) If that number is less than the current version, I display the latest version notes and update the value to the current version.

Answer (score 2):

For displaying the change log, you can also you localized (i.e. loaded from res folder) html  in the dialog:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.changelog_dialog_title));
            dialog.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

            WebView wv = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
            wv.loadData(getString(R.string.changelog_dialog_text), "text/html", "utf-8");
            dialog.setView(wv);

            dialog.setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok), new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```

The magic is how to code the html 'page' in res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="changelog_dialog_text">
<![CDATA[<b>Version 1.3.0:</b>
        <ul>
         <li>Change 1</li>
         <li>Change 2</li>
        </ul> 
]]>
</string>
```